# Google Apps Script - Converting file times out, script bails, error not catchable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, file-conversion

I am converting MS office files to google files (gsheet, gdoc, mostly). I got my script working well enough, but google can't convert some files for whatever reason. When this happens, the convert times out, I get an error message in the script editor window, and the entire script exits (including functions that called this function). Here is the error:

> We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

Try, catch doesn't work here because this kind of error doesn't seem to get caught.

I was thinking of implementing a timer so the function is terminated if it takes longer than 5 seconds or so, but I can't seem to find any way to make that happen.

Here is my code:

```
function convertFile(oldFile, newMimeType, safeKeepingFolder){
  try{

      var name = oldFile.getName().split(".")[0];
      var ID = oldFile.getId();
      var folderID = Drive.Files.get(ID).parents[0].id; 

      var oldBlob = oldFile.getBlob();
      var newFile = {       
              title: name,
              mimeType: newMimeType,
              parents: [{id: folderID}],
       }

       //This is where it times out:
       Drive.Files.insert(newFile, oldBlob, {
         convert: true});

       moveFile(oldFile, safeKeepingFolder);   
  }
  catch(e) {
    Utils.errorLog(e, errorSsId, "convertFile");
    console.error('convertFile yielded an error: ' + e);
  }

}
```

Comment: How big are the files it fails on? Also, consider trying `copy` instead of `insert`.

Comment: The file it is failing on is 274K.

I tried to use copy but it is surprisingly hard to find documentation on how to use Drive.Files.copy do you know how I would format that command?

Comment: 274kb isn't big enough that it should be posing a real challenge... are there complexities like footnotes, automatic fields, excessive chart / images, and / or bound macros that are present in the failed files, but not in the ones which convert?.

Comment: For `Drive.Files.copy()` the arguments are similar as to `Drive.Files.insert()`. The `resource` details metadata for the new file, such as its name and parent folder (e.g. `{title: "My File Copy", parents: [{id: someId}]}`), the fileId is the file to be copied, and the optional params are things like `{convert: true, ocr: true}`. See https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy for the supported list of `resource` and `optionalArgs` parameters. Most importantly, you don't have to worry about the to-and-from `Blob` conversion, since Drive already has the bytes.

Comment: Thank you! It's always good to know why the file won't convert, but my issue is that I want to run this on every account in our office and there will likely be several files that won't convert for whatever reason. 

The big problem is that I have no way of handling these errors, I can't put these files on a list to deal with them individually or simply skip them to leave them, the entire script just quits when the error shows up.